# To push Linear Layout with soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-activity, android-linearlayout, android-softkeyboard

Hi I've an xml layout in which I've two buttons at the bottom of the parent layout. Here whenever the soft keyboard opens those buttons are hidden, therefore I need to push the button above with the keyboard. I've posted my xml layout here, please refer to it and help me achieving this.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/leftPane"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/Left_listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#0A2F41"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:listSelector="#335E73"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rightPane"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchkeyword_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_close"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/right_listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/searchkeyword_editText"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_linearLayout"
        android:background="#000"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cancel_textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/apply_textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#02B5CC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Apply"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also in my Manifest I've added the below line in order to achieve the above action.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

I'd like to have something like [this](http://prntscr.com/biojwn).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```